# ¿Como darle estilo a un echo o colocar un alert en codigo php?

Tags: javascript, php

tengo este codigo php:

```
**<?php
require "conexion.php";
session_start();
if($_POST){
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
$sql ="select id, password , nombre, tipo_usuario from usuarios where usuario='$usuario'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$num = $resultado->num_rows;
 
if ($num >0) {
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    $password_bd = $row ['password'];
    $pass_c = sha1($password);
     if ($password_bd ==$pass_c) {
      
        $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['nombre']= $row['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario']= $row['tipo_usuario'];
        header("location: principal.php");
     }
     else{
         echo "contraseña incorrecta"
        
   
     }
}
else{
   echo "no existe el usuario";
}
}
?>**
```

todo funciona correctamente lo unico que quiero es cambiar los echo por alertas o darle estilo para que me salgan en medio de la pagina , de color rojo... no se, agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Si en el echo metes algo a lo que darle estilo, puedes darle el estilo que quieras. Ya sea usando un css de algo, o añadiendo el style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres agregar estilo a un echo, usa algún contenedor al que puedas darle estilo:

```
echo "<div style='color: red;'>contraseña incorrecta</div>";
```

Si quieres emitir un `alert()` del tipo javascript:

```
echo "<script>alert('hola');</script>";
```

Y por último, usando alguna clase aplicada:

```
<style type="text/css">
.verde{
    color: green;
}
</style>
<?php
    echo "<div class='verde'>contraseña incorrecta</div>";
?>
```

Comment: he intentado mil veces la opcion dos y no me funciona :c

Comment: Corregi recien el codigo por errores de comillas, checkea ahora.

Comment: ya, ya me funciono! muchas gracias bro!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta, solo añadiré la opción de meterle el class igual.

Comment: bro, como hago para que el echo con estilo me salga debajo de un input o metido en un div... ?

Comment: Como el último ejemplo que puse?

Comment: si, alli le das color y todo, pero me gustaria colocar ese echo dentro de un div que ya tengo... no se si me hago entender, para que no salga arriba en la nada sino adentro de un contenedor

Comment: Tendrías que hacer una nueva pregunta dando a explicar ese tema, a ver si se puede hacer o no. Por que el problema de esta pregunta, ya fue resuelto.